# Close document window by accident Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

While I was learning to code by using the microsoft visual studio, I closed the document window by accident (CTRL+F4) and now I can't see the code on the IDE. I tried to restart Microsoft Visual Studio and nothing happened. I even tried the command "Window.CloseDocumentWindow" on command windows and nothing.
The code works well when I try to debug but it didn't show the code itself

[image: Here is the picture of the IDE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1) Open Tools->Import and Export Settings...

2) Select "Import selected environment settings" and click Next

4) Save your current settings if desired and click Next

5) Select the default settings file of your choosing (EX: General) and click Next

6) Unselect "All Settings", then select "Window Layouts" under General and click Finish

7) Close the dialog and your layout should reset to the selected default

source:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/258393/reset-window-layout.html